# is there any direct way in C# to optimize a math function or minimize a parameter in an expression?

Tags: c#-4.0, machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to implement an algorithm in C# that has some math function inside like :

Minimize a  ||xu( i )  -  ∑j aj( i ) bj ||2  +  β || a( i ) ||1

but I'm not sure if there is any direct method in C# for optimizing and I couldn't find any thing in forums , or maybe you can offer  any suggestion to solve this optimization problem in C# !?

Comment: (i) You are looking for a **solver** that has a C# interface / C# binding. (ii) I understand the first term in your function (method of least squares). I don't understand the term starting with beta. Could you explain that? (iii) If you just need least squares then it should not be too difficult to find / interface a specific solver for that. If you really need general nonlinear optimization, I would recommend [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/) for that but I believe it would be on overkill in your case. I have no idea how good IPOPT's C# interface is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several solvers with C# bindings that could be suitable for your problem, for example:

- [MS Solver Foundation](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation), Microsoft's platform for mathematical optimization, that provides solvers for a large range of problems, including unconstrained and constrained least squares. Some effort to dig into the API, but in return derivatives are automatically computed etc.
- [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/) provides a large range of different optimizers and is available in [C#](http://www.alglib.net/download.php).
- IPOPT was mentioned in Ali's comment above. I have developed the C# binding to IPOPT, and it is available for download [here](http://code.google.com/p/csipopt/). I am of course biased, but personally I believe that the API is fairly straightforward. You need to manually provide the derivatives if you are using *csipopt*. (There is actually also a library that incorporates *csipopt and* provides automated derivative computation, [Funclib](http://funclib.codeplex.com/).)
- COBYLA2 (if you have nonlinear constraints) and BOBYQA (if you have bound or no constraints) are derivative-free direct search methods developed by Michael Powell. I have ported these solvers to C#, 100% managed code. The C# COBYLA2 project is available [here](https://github.com/cureos/cscobyla), and the C# BOBYQA project is available [here](https://github.com/cureos/csbobyqa).